Do I need transit visa for 2 hours layover with different terminals?
I will be traveling from Hungary to Dubai via Wizz Air, and then from Dubai to Bangalore via IndiGo on August 19th 2024. I have a two-hour layover between these flights at Dubai Airport. I will be landing at DXB Terminal 2 and departing from DXB Terminal 1, which are different terminals. Do I need a transit visa in this case?

I suppose the two flights are booked separately (self-transfer)? Do you have checked bags? What is your citizenship? Note that if this is indeed a self transfer and you have checked bags this is extremely short and very risky.

Whizz air does not sell connecting flights, so I assume these are two separate tickets.

I have a two-hour layover between these flights at Dubai Airport.

This is extremely risky. I would not recommend doing this. If you miss your second flight, you will have to buy a new same day ticket on the spot which can be very expensive. You will need to exit the plane, go through Dubai immigration, wait for your bags to appear (if you have checked any), transfer to the other terminal and arrive at the check-in or bag drop counter before it closes (typically 60 minutes before departure).
Even if you have no checked bags and can check in online, you still need to go through security and be a the gate 25 minutes before departure.

Do I need a transit visa in this case?

That obviously depends on your citizenship, which you haven't disclosed. If you don't qualify for Visa free entry or Visa on arrival you need full credentials to enter the United Arab Emirates (UAE).
Transit Visa are only issued by Emirates and Etihad. Since you don't fly these airlines you will need a full Visa.
